# Is there any way of getting date in more columns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this script that gives me a date in column s when column q is edited is there a way to put the date in column i when column g is edited and column u when column t is edited?Many Thanks

> 

```html
//CORE VARIABLES
// The column you want to check if something is entered.
var COLUMNTOCHECK = 17;
// Where you want the date time stamp offset from the input location. [row, column]
var DATETIMELOCATION = [0,2];
// Sheet you are working on
var SHEETNAME = 'Sheet1'
 
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  //checks that we're on the correct sheet.
  if( sheet.getSheetName() == SHEETNAME ) { 
    var selectedCell = ss.getActiveCell();
    //checks the column to ensure it is on the one we want to cause the date to appear.
    if( selectedCell.getColumn() == COLUMNTOCHECK) { 
      var dateTimeCell = selectedCell.offset(DATETIMELOCATION[0],DATETIMELOCATION[1]);
      dateTimeCell.setValue(new Date());
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you have already the script then modify it for more columns... what's the problem you facing in that?

Comment: i have tried modifying it but I dont know how to ?

Comment: i tried putting in more columns but it doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the modified code as per your requirement

```
//CORE VARIABLES
// The column you want to check if something is entered.
var COLUMNTOCHECK = [7,17,20];
// Where you want the date time stamp offset from the input location. [row, column]
var DATETIMELOCATION = [0,2];
// Sheet you are working on
var SHEETNAME = 'Sheet1'
 
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  //checks that we're on the correct sheet.
  if( sheet.getSheetName() == SHEETNAME ) { 
    var selectedCell = ss.getActiveCell();
    //checks the column to ensure it is on the one we want to cause the date to appear.
    for(i in COLUMNTOCHECK){
      if( selectedCell.getColumn() == COLUMNTOCHECK[i]) { 
        var dateTimeCell = selectedCell.offset(DATETIMELOCATION[0],DATETIMELOCATION[1]);
        dateTimeCell.setValue(new Date());
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  const sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const columnsToCheck = [7, 17, 20];
  const dateTimeLocation = [2, 2, 1];
  const colInd = columnsToCheck.indexOf(e.range.columnStart)
  if (sheet.getName() === 'Sheet1' && colInd > -1) {
    e.range.offset(0, dateTimeLocation[colInd]).setValue(e.value ? new Date() : null)
  }
}
```